# RESTful stateless service and KeyChain. Go stateless or nor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asp.net-web-api

I am planning to make a ASP.NET Wep API server and a IOS client.

1. From what i have read, the KeyChain is the only place to store IOS sensitive data such as passwords.
2. Considering a RESTful stateless service: the username and password must be sent to the service with each request.

This stateless service seems to bring the following two extra operations with each call:

- Go go KeyChain and get credentials
- Validate the credentials

Q1:Does that mean that for every request password must be retrieved from the KeyChain and passed to the server?

Q2: That makes me wonder, go stateless or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keychain is the place to **persistently** store sensitive information, yes.
If you are using a username and password and keep it for the duration, storing it in memory (RAM) is typically ok. If you wish to remember it for next time so the user must never provide it again, you must store it in the keychain.

Typically you store the password in memory (even for a session) once retrieved from keychain.